# JSON Objects merge issue from an Object Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, merge, push

The logic is written at the Button Click event, which fetches an array of objects. In the ForEach Loop, I convert each object to JSON but i am unable to merge it into a final json object. I am getting the error as  **'string.Concat(params string[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

String json = "";

String jsonoutput = "";

foreach (SAFWebReference.Usagr value in response.PRoles)

        {

           json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(value);
           jsonoutput = jsonoutput.Concat(json);

        }
}
```

Comment: You can not concat  json strings to form a valid json... Serialize *response.PRoles* .... `{a:1}` is a valid json but `{a:1}{a:2}` not...

Comment: use jsonoutput = jsonoutput + json; if it is just purely for merge and not a valid json at the end

Comment: ...and `Concat` is a `static` method, so you cannot use it on an instance as you do.

Comment: why can't your serialize respnse.PRoles directly?

Comment: Is this giving error? new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response.PRoles);

Comment: Seems like you want `jsonoutput = string.Concat(jsonoutput, json);` but I don't think you are on the right path....

Comment: @techspider: Thank You very much, I serialized the whole string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to serialize the complete list object instead of serializing one item at at a time and trying to merge strings manually.

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response.PRoles);
```